# pandas test with true / false logic to whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan':[80,5,21],'Feb':[85,7,19],'Mar':[75,15,25]})

   Jan   Feb   Mar
0   80    85    75
1    5     7    15
2   23    18    25
```

I would like to return True or False if the values are > 20

```
     Jan    Feb    Mar
0   True   True   True
1  False  False  False
2   True  False   True
```

How would you go about doing this in pandas?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks that answers my question! Simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you said: `df>20`.